# Is it possible to export 2 OxyPlot PlotModels in one .png file?

Tags: plot, export, png, oxyplot

Currently I am able to export one `PlotModel` as a `.png` at a time, using:

```
public void CreatePNG(PlotModel plotModel, string fileName, Stream stream)
{
    var pngExporter = new PngExporter { Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White };
    pngExporter.Export(plotModel, stream);        
}
```

Here is the `.png` output of the `PlotModel`
[image]

Is there a way to export 2 `PlotModel`s such that they look like this in the `.png` file?

[image]

Or, can I concatenate 2 `.png` files??

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to export multiple `OxyPlot` plots in a `.png` file, by converting them into `Bitmap`.

Here a sample code:

```
            var stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            var stream2 = new MemoryStream();
            var pngExporter = new PngExporter {Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White};
            var pngExporter2 = new PngExporter {Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White};
            pngExporter.Export(plotModel1, stream1);
            pngExporter2.Export(plotModel2, stream2);

            System.Drawing.Bitmap b1 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream1));
            System.Drawing.Bitmap b2 = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Image.FromStream(stream2));

            System.Drawing.Bitmap img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(600, 800);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);

            g.DrawImage(b1, 0, 0);
            g.DrawImage(b2, 0, 400);

            img.Save(stream.ToString());
```

Comment: `PngExporter` unfortunately no longer exists in OxyPlot.  :-(